# Using MEF and MAF together

Tags: .net, mef, maf

I want to compose my plugins with *MEF* (Managed Extensibility Framework) and run them in a separate process with *MAF* (Managed AddIn Framework).

So

- First, is it possible?
- Then, if possible how? (Any small example will be great.)

> How can MEF and MAF work together and complement each other?

**Make Myself More Specific:**

Well i do not want to write Pipeline in MAF...

I just want to use ease of MEF to create plugins and use isolation of MAF to run each plugin as a separete process...

I check http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/02/maf-and-mef.html site but he also write pipeline...

Comment: Why is pipeline not ok for you ?

Comment: I have to update many interfaces...For all plugins i have to write adapters, views again and again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very general... short answer: yes, this is possible.

As for some useful resources (with some sample source etc.):

- http://web.archive.org/web/20140114182810/http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/02/maf-and-mef.html
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/cda7966e-9e81-4242-b613-129be6018f19
- http://www.slideshare.net/infusiondev/mef-deep-dive
- http://mrpfister.com/journal/mef-maf-and-all-c-plugins-in-between/
- http://emcpadden.wordpress.com/2008/12/07/managed-extensibility-framework-and-others/